# The constructor "public GUI()" is called twice, causing two similar windows to open

Tags: java, class, server, constructor, jframe

I am currently working on a test project using windows and servers. I have it working so far (doing what's supposed to be doing), but the only problem is that the constructor is being called twice, making the code to display two similar windows. Help!
Here is my code:

(you can ignore the mouse listener parts, I don't really think that's the problem).

```java
public class RummyClient implements Runnable{
public GUI gui = new GUI();
public static Servidor servidor;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        servidor = new Servidor(25565, "localhost");
        new Thread(new RummyClient()).start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            gui.repaint();
        }
    }
    
    public class GUI extends JFrame {
    
        public int clickedX = 0;
        public int clickedY = 0;
    
        public String stage = "";
    
        public boolean start = false;
    
        public GUI() {
            setTitle("Rummy");
            setSize(1280, 720);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            setResizable(false);
            
            Board board = new Board();
            setContentPane(board);
            getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
    
            Move move = new Move();
            addMouseMotionListener(move);
    
            Click click = new Click();
            addMouseListener(click);
            pack();
    
            stage = "start";
            System.out.println("created");
        }
    
        public class Board extends JPanel {
    
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                try {
                    Image board = ImageIO.read(new File("client/src/imgs/board.jpg")).getScaledInstance(1280, 720, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, this);
                    switch (stage) {
                        case "start":
                            Image playButtonNP = ImageIO.read(new File("client/src/imgs/play.png")).getScaledInstance(406, 220, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    
                            Image rummyTitle = ImageIO.read(new File("client/src/imgs/rummy.png")).getScaledInstance(526, 340, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                            g.drawImage(rummyTitle, 376, 0, this);
                            if (start){
                                g.drawImage(playButtonNP, 448, 360, this);
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("error!");
                }
            }
            
        }
    
        public class Move implements MouseMotionListener {
    
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    
            }
        }
    
        public class Click implements MouseListener{
    
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                
            }
    
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                clickedX = e.getX();
                clickedY = e.getY();
            }
    
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                clickedX = 0;
                clickedY = 0;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    
            }
        }
    
        public void start() {
            this.start = true;
        }
    }
    
    static class Servidor extends RummyClient{
        Socket s;
        PrintWriter out;
        Scanner in;
    
        public Servidor(int port, String ip) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
            this.s = new Socket(ip, port);
            this.out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            this.in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            Thread input = new Thread(new Input());
            input.start();
        }
    
        public void send(String text) {
            out.println(text);
            out.flush();
        }
    
        class Input implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String incoming = in.nextLine();
                    switch (incoming) {
                        case "ready":
                            gui.start();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Servidor` extends from `RummyClient`, so when you create an instance of `Servidor`, it will also run it's parent constructor - hence two instances.  And, don't do `while(true) { gui.repaint(); }`.  I can't even begin to explain what a terribly bad idea this is.  Don't load images in your paint method, this is going to slow down you paint passes - pre-load your images and switch the them based on the current state. Swing is not thread save, so you should be updating the UI or any state the UI relies on from out side the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: You should start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency) and probably make use of [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: As to how you might go about fixing your core issues - start by separating your workflows.  The "comms" layer should have direct connection to the UI and should instead communicate via an observer pattern (ie listener), this way you isolate it's responsibility and focus it's work.  The UI should be a stand alone entity, which makes use of a model, which represents the current state, which the UI should renderer. Again, changes to the model would be communicated to the UI via an observer pattern.  This is a very common workflow - you should do some research into "model-view-controller"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.